# Fastest way to check if any item in a list is a numeric type?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a Python loop that's expected to run billions of times, and as such it need to be as tightly optimized as possible.

One of the operations is checking if a list of ~50 items contains a float or an integer.

I know about the `any()` builtin method, but is it the fastest way to do this kind of checking?

Comment: Given that your lists already exist, and you do not know what is in them, `any` is the best way to perform this test. You should ask yourself, however, how you can design your code such that only the lists you are looking for will even end up being processed. This design really depends on the source of your lists.

Comment: This may be a good question for [codereview.se] if you expand to show your current solution and some sample data. That site exists to help optimize working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of question about how fast or slow something is can be tested for yourself using the `timeit` module, though it can be hard to know some different ways to test agains. Below I have tested several options and included the timings. Overall, for a 50 element list, checking types is very unlikely to be the bottleneck in a complex program

```
#initialize a list of integers to create a random list from
ch=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

#Fill a list with random integers, 5000 items in length just for a bigger test
arr=[random.choice(ch) for _ in range(5000)]

#Add a single string to the end for a worst case iterating scenario
arr.extend('a')

#check the end of the list for funsies
arr[-5:]
[3, 6, 7, 4, 'a']

#Check for stringiness with the OP-mentioned any() function
%timeit any(type(i)==str for i in arr)
2.52 ms ± 325 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#Since isinstance() is the more pythonic way of assertive type-checking, let's see if it makes a difference
%timeit any(isinstance(i, str) for i in arr)
2.05 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#Define a function to make time checking easier
def check_list(a):
    for i in a:
        #stop iteration if a string is found
        if isinstance(i, str):
            return True
        else:
            return False

#Try out our function
%timeit check_list(arr)
711 ns ± 85.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

#let's pretend booleans are numbers to math up a solution
%timeit sum(map(lambda x:isinstance(x, str), arr))>0
2.86 ms ± 280 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#conversion to a set takes some time but reduces the number of items we need to check, so let's try it
%timeit any(type(i)==str for i in set(arr))
99.4 µs ± 3.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

#Let's try our custom function with a set
%timeit check_list(set(arr))
115 µs ± 29.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

def check_set(a):
    #let's convert the list to a set inside the function to see what happens
    for i in set(a):
        if isinstance(i, str):
            return True
        else:
            return False

%timeit check_set(arr)
94.7 µs ± 1.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

We have a winner on this synthetic problem, but more importantly we can see how we tested several different options

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

**use** iteration_utilities

```py
from iteration_utilities import any_isinstance

ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
all_isinstance(ids, int) # True
ids = [1,2,'aa',4,5]
all_isinstance(ids, int) # False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).